# Is it possible to capture browser back button press

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am updating the page via

```
render :update do |page|
  page.replace_html 'intainer', :partial => 'users/partial/trest'
end
```

So, when a user presses back, they (apparently) get taken back two pages. I would like to continue to use the page.replace, however, I would like to know if there is a way to capture the back button press and call another page.replace to effectively change the page back to its previous state instead.

I suppose the alternative is to put a 'back' button, but that is less desirable.

Comment: Please don't screw up normal browser functionality. Having to do so is a sign that your website is broken.

Comment: Or a sign that you are trying to increase performance in a sensitive environment by using replace_html instead of loading a new page. y'know, either one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i don't know ruby, but back button is browser stuff and ruby is server side language.
You need to work with javascript here to do that.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but I am wondering how is it possible. Rails has a lot of javascript helper methods, but I would be fine writing the javascript myself as well.

Comment: Mmm.. this is always hard since all functions work like when user clicks [x] or go to outer link by typing other address script will execute. You probably need to keep on track on what's inside URL part to do this work somehow. But javascript for this is easy:
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  alert("Eu, Dude stop");
 }

Comment: Hmm, I think I will do this with an on-page back button. Thanks

Comment: Yep, it's probably wisest solution if you need that kind of functionality.